# IFS=$'\n' deleted the "n"

Tags: shell, for-loop, sh, ifs

I have problem with "IFS=$'\n'.

```
old_IFS=$IFS
file="Good morning
Good morning
Good morning
Good morning
Good morning"

IFS=$'\n'
for line in $file
    do
       echo $line
done
IFS=$old_IFS
```

When I execute the script:

```
Good mor
i
g
Good mor
i
g
Good mor
i
g
Good mor
i
g
Good mor
i
g
```

The "n" is deleted.
I would like to view the files line by line

Comment: Which shell are you using? Does it support `$'...'` string syntax? (Rhetorical question; clearly not.)

Comment: if you're using `#!/bin/sh` at the top of you script, try changing to `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/ksh`. Good luck.

Comment: It must be written in shell. I am using #!/bin/sh. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to iterate over multi-line data (whether or not your shell supports `$'...'`) is with a `while` loop that calls `read` repeatedly:

```
while read -r; do
    echo "$REPLY"
done <<EOF
$file
EOF
```

Comment: +1 Great to know.  I'd note that `REPLY` is Bash variable not available in all shells.

Comment: Right, I forgot to double-check that. If you are providing a specific variable to use in place of `REPLY`, you should also set `IFS` to the empty string to prevent word-splitting (which could drop any leading or trailing whitespace in the line): `IFS= read -r line`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, I don't think the shell you're using supports `$'...'` syntax.

If your system is using Dash as `sh`, you should be able to assign `IFS` to a new line by assigning it to an empty or unassigned variable.  For example, `n=""; IFS=$n` would allow you to split by new lines.  This is a hack, and only works because an empty variable is interpreted as a new line to the interpreter.

You could also read from a here string in shells like Bash, using `<<<word`.

```
file="Good morning
Good morning
Good morning
Good morning
Good morning"

while read line; do
    echo $line
done <<<"$file"
```

Otherwise, you can just read from a file line by line.

```
while read -r line; do 
    echo "$line"
done < file
```

Comment: That won't work, but you can easily set `IFS` to a literal newline by putting it in quotes. So `IFS='` on one line and a lone `'` on the next line. (Sorry, no code formatting in comments.)

Comment: Also the unquoted `$line` is still problematic because it is subject to wildcard expansion; you need to use `"$line"`.

Comment: No problem, please see my updated post for some further explanation.

Comment: ...might even make it `while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; done <file`, if we didn't want to strip leading whitespace. Depends on just how literal we want the inputs. :)